# onClick inline function works different from outside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, inline-functions

I have a newbie question that is probably really easily explained. I have an image that has an onClick property added to it. If I call an inline function to log something, it works as expected. It logs to the console whenever the image is clicked. However, whenever I have an outside function called there, it gets clicked every second which is because I have data coming in every second updating a part of the code.

My question is, why does the inline function work and the other way doesn't? What am I missing here?

inline version...

```
return(
    <>
        <SettingsButton src="./img/leaf.png" alt="" onClick={() => { console.log("button clicked");}}/>
    </>
);
```

and the other way that doesn't work as intended...

```
function handleClick() {
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
}

return(
    <>
        <SettingsButton src="./img/leaf.png" alt="" onClick={handleClick()}/>
    </>
);
```

Comment: Remove the parenthesis `onClick={handleClick()}` should be `onClick={handleClick}`. --- with the parenthesis, you CALL the function. Without, you assign the fonction to the event handler.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it was super simple. Thank you! This was exactly what was wrong

Comment: `this` ?? :D Really? hahah

Comment: Ketan's answer is good now... I suggest you accept it and close `this` lol

Comment: ```this``` is getting funny and I am a bit embarrassing now :P

Comment: Programming is fun. Keep `this` funny. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are calling function as soon as the component is loaded by writing it as `handleClick()`, so the browser does not wait for you to click as it should be.

```
handleClick =()=> {
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
}

return(
    <>
        <SettingsButton src="./img/leaf.png" alt="" onClick={handleClick}/>
    </>
);
```

Comment: It **doesn’t** need this. `handleClick` is defined in the scope of the function. It isn’t a method on the class.

Comment: if it's a class-based component it then it's required to use ```this```. Please correct me if m wrong.

Comment: Your wrong. Even if it is a class based component, the function is being assigned to a variable that is in the same scope as the return statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Will read more, will you be kind enough to forward some link to the resource, I am often confused about ```this```
got it, it's not outside ```render```. so the scope is the same.